# How to turn off app.use(express.static('/public')); Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using Express js. In the root folder, I have a `public` folder which contains subfolders `stylesheets`, `javascripts`, `fonts`, `images` and `html`. I want to protect my assets if the user is not logged in. For example, if someone opens the web browser and without login make a request for `http://localhost:3000/images/hello.jpg` then the request should be redirected to login page.

To achieve this I am using `express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))` conditionally.

**Challenge 1**

Login page also having some 4 to 5 assets (CSS and JS files), which are placed in the same public folder.

**Challenge 2**

I am using this code `express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))` like this:

```
if(userIsLoggedIn){
   express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))
}else{
   //what to do here???
   //I need a code here which makes public folder as non-static folder
}
```

For example, we have 2 users A and B. Both users are using different computers. User A is doing successful login and at the server, we are setting the `public` folder as `static` but user B has not done login he is now directly accessing the assets and he is able to access.

This is happening because we are not setting the public folder as static on user basis we are making it static if any of user do a successful login.

Comment: Add a middleware to check for authentication before all protected assets.

Answer (score 2):

you can add an extra middleware before the `express.static` to force a user validation.

```
var VerifyUser = require('./verifyuser');
app.use(VerifyUser, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


//VerifyUser code
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if(user.isLogged) 
      next();
    else
     next(err); //presume you have some error handler middleware
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to simply mkdir an empty directory and point to it. Or add files to it that you don't mind having public.

```
express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/someemptydirectory'))
```